# How to get a string from a form input select option

Tags: php, html

I have this form so that people can insert some data into a database.

```
            <form action="publicar_action.php"  method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="concNome"  placeholder="nome do concurso"> <br>

            <select name="concInstrumento">
                <option>guitarra</option>
                <option>flauta</option>
            </select>

            <input type="date" name="concDataDE"    ><br>
            <input type="date" name="concDataATE"   ><br>
            <input type="text" name="concDescricao" placeholder="Descrição"><br><br>

            <input type="submit">       
        </form>
```

And i have this database `mr_concursos`, wich has 2 tables: `guitarra` and `flauta`. 
What I wanted to do is to insert the data in the corresponding table. That table would be selected by the option chosen by the user on the form.

Like this:

```
    <?php   
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mr_concursos');
        $concNome = $_POST['concNome'];
        $concInstrumento = $_POST['concInstrumento'];
        $concDataDE = $_POST['concDataDE'];
        $concDataATE = $_POST['concDataATE'];
        $concDescricao = $_POST['concDescricao'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $concInstrumento (nome, instrumento, dataDE, dataATE, descricao) VALUES ('$concNome', '$concInstrumento', '$concDataDE', '$concDataATE', '$concDescricao')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        header('Location: publicar.php');
```

Both tables have the same columns.

For some reason it doesn't work.

If instead of an select/option tag, I use just a simple text field, and write the name of the table, it will only be inserted into the table `guitarra`. it doesn't work on `flauta`...

Do you know why?

Comment: Why you have the same table structure for 2 instruments...so if in the future you have like 100 instruments, you are going to have 100 tables with the same structure?....why not just one table called InstrumentDetails and another table called InstrumentTypes, or something like that?

Comment: I am new to coding and many of my actions will have an inexperienced character. As i'm learning new stuff i adapt what I wrote.
  I'll take your advise for sure. If I want to retrieve data from the 'InstrumentDetails' table, but just from a kind of instrument how should i do it? (probably using the 'InstrumentTypes' table... but i don't understand how to relate them)

Comment: In the InstrumentDetails table you need to include the primary key for the InstrumentType that you are referencing

Comment: If the tables has the same structure, you could use just one table, and a field like 'TypeOfInstrument' to identify different instruments. Anyway, what is the value of $concInstrumento? I think it probably isn't the expected value, try to set a value to the options: `<option value='guitarra'>guitarra</option>`

Answer (score 0):

You have been missing the following constraints over the `form` and `PHP conditions`.

HTML:

1. Option Tag missing the value
2. Submit button missing the name

PHP

1. `isset()` condition missing since if the page is posted we have to check it using this.
2. Insert statement missing the ticks over to the table names that you put inside the table name

Hence your Entire code should be as follows.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="publicar_action.php"  method="POST">
<input type="text" name="concNome"  placeholder="nome do concurso"> <br>
<select name="concInstrumento">
<option value="guitarra">guitarra</option>
<option value="flauta">flauta</option>
</select>

<input type="date" name="concDataDE"><br>
<input type="date" name="concDataATE"><br>
<input type="text" name="concDescricao" placeholder="Descrição"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="save"  value="Submit">       
</form>
```

**publicar_action.php**

```
<?php   
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mr_concursos');
if(isset($_POST['save'])){ // where save is the name of the input button
$concNome = $_POST['concNome'];
$concInstrumento = $_POST['concInstrumento'];
$concDataDE = $_POST['concDataDE'];
$concDataATE = $_POST['concDataATE'];
$concDescricao = $_POST['concDescricao'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO $concInstrumento (`nome`, `instrumento`, `dataDE`, `dataATE`, `descricao`) VALUES ('".$concNome."', '".$concInstrumento."', '".$concDataDE."', '".$concDataATE."', '".$concDescricao."')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
header('Location: publicar.php');
}
?>
```

In order to Ensure the proper working of the Insert Statement into the database you can follow the points.

> **Note:** You first put echo to the Insert Statement and then break the execution by putting the exit; and you copy the statement that is echoed and place it in SQL of the DB and then check whether any error occurs in insertion. If no error occurs remove the echo and delete the exit;

Hope the explanations are clear and it will be helpful for you to rectify the errors if it occurs in future.

Happy coding:)